# Is there a layer 1, 2, 5 and 6 DDoS attack?

Tags: denial-of-service, ddos

I'm doing some research on DDoS attacks, and I seem to only be finding information on layer 3,4 and 7 attacks.  When I saw 3/4 and 7 DDoS attacks, I figured they were the most popular, but there were also layers 1,2,5 and 6 layers as well.

Are there more?

Comment: How do you imagine a DDoS occurring on layers 1/2? All nodes in the distributed attack would have to be local, thereby limited the "distributedness" of the attack.

Comment: The way I understand it, layer 1 is the attacker, layer 2 the bots they gained control of, right?

Comment: You are referring to the OSI model, aren't you?

Comment: @Ulkoma  I suppose.  I've basically been doing research on DDoS attacks, and I guess I got confused about the layers.  I kept seeing people refer to layer 3/4 and layer 7, which is application layer, but nothing on layer 5 or 6.  So I was wondering what those could be.  But I guess I should refer to the OSI model?

Comment: hold on - what do you mean by "layers"?

Comment: @schroeder  From what I can gather, layer 3-4 attacks deal with bombarding a network with illegitmate traffic, usually done by the use of botnets.  A layer 7 attack does not work the same. It basically attacks the application layer, and you can attack slowly, and not use botnets.  So I was wondering if there was a layer 6 or 5 attack.

Comment: Oh.. I think I am referring to the OSI model, I just wasn't clear on that.  I'm looking at a graph now.

Comment: PLEASE use terminology that is industry standard. This question is meaningless if you invent terms.

Comment: Also, please consider sharing your research results. Here's what I got from a quick google search: [Attack possibilities by OSI layer](https://www.us-cert.gov/sites/default/files/publications/DDoS%20Quick%20Guide.pdf). I guess this is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Um... ok.  What terms was I inventing?  I've been reading some scholarly articles that referred to attacks as level 3, 4 and 7, and I was asking people if there were other layers of attacks, for clarification.  It wasn't an attempt to invent terms, it was a question, to gain some understanding on a subject I'm not an expert in from experts in this field.

Comment: @RahilArora Thanks, I'll take a look at that. I didn't realize I was referring to the OSI model.

Comment: @user3577397: You're welcome. Just an FYI: Make sure you tell us about the efforts you have already made (If you haven't done any, make sure you do it!) or what you already know about the topic, very clearly, while asking your question on SE network.

Comment: @RahilArora  Thanks, I'll try that.  I basically have a conceptual understanding of it now.  I learned about botnets, and I learned that these attacks can also be carried out by taking advantage of open DNS resolvers.  I've mostly been trying to see if there's a way to mitigate these attacks. Some people are suggesting source-end (which I imagine is at the ISP?) defense to mitigate DDoS.  Others have suggested a combination of rate-limiting and Access Control list.  It seems like there's no definitive way to defend against these attacks or ways to stop them.  But there are many suggestions.

Comment: Yes. The answer will always be "It depends". It really depends on the [context](http://www.rahilarora.com/2015/04/19/context/) (the scenario for which you're implementing the defense).

Comment: @RahilArora - Great article, man.  Good points throughout.  Also, I dig the website design. Very clean looking

Comment: [Practical example of a layer-1 DoS tool](http://etherkiller.org/)

Comment: As an aside, you should know that the OSI model is irrelevant, since it is not in use and the TCP/IP model does not fit well with the OSI model. Despite that, the terminology - such as "layer 7" meaning the application layer - still has stuck, which is why you wont often see layers 5/6 mentioned, since these dont strictly exist as such in TCP/IP...

Answer (score 1):

> ...when I saw 3/4 and 7 DDoS attacks, I figured they were the most popular, but there were also layers 1,2,5 and 6 layers as well.

The OSI model does not have much common with reality anymore, at least not with layers 5..7. Instead you will find layer 4 functionality packed into layer 7 (like with Websockets) or layer 5 (session) functionality within the application layer (HTTP cookies) etc. Therefore you might better refer to the [TCP/IP model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) which merges OSI layer 5..7 into a single application layer and don't look for separate attacks at each of these layers.

DOS of OSI layer 1 (physical) is of course physical too: just somehow damage the cabling, like using a nuclear bomb (either by destroying the cables or by EMP). A distributed DOS would be much harder, because you would need to be of course physically present somehow.  At layers 1 and 2 you also have various DOS attacks against WLAN (just google and you'll find some paper), but distributed DOS would more mean attacks against the underlying control functionality. There might be some "packet of death" attacks which make certain network cards croak but you would need upper layers to get access to these cards first within a distributed attack.

Comment: DDoS, not DoS.  So a Layer 1 DDoS would be a horde of people banging at your cable with hammers, all at the same time.

Comment: @armani Thanks - That makes sense now lol.  I was reading up on it,but the writers weren't referring to these models, so I was getting confused.